Why is the twitter handle for crypto.SE inactive from Feb 2023?
The twitter handle for crypto.SE used to be active earlier but has been silent from Feb 2023 - what's the reason?

Due to changes in Twitter's API, these Twitter bots (for the SE sites that had them) were shut off as of February 8, 2023. See Catija's MSE post here for more details.

Thank you - didn't know it was a bot. There were hardly a couple of tweets on any day, so I assumed it was an actual human operating the account.
